# How to force manifest.json to refresh on existing Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, manifest, progressive-web-apps

Within my PWA, I want to ensure any changes to the `manifest.json` file are forced to be applied to any device that either already has the PWA added to home screen or ensure Chrome does not cache the file so old settings are not used when adding to home screen

I've tried changing the name of the manifest file and the `<link>` value but this does not seem to work on the next visit

Is there a definitive way to ensure the up to date manifest file is used?

Comment: This is probably rather late, but if you are using ReactJS, there is a great guide on their site for this. https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, changes should be reflected within a day or two of the PWA being launched, after certain fields manifest file have been updated. There are minor differences between Chrome on desktop and Chrome on Android on which fields will trigger an update. One of the easiest things to do is change the `icons` or the `theme_color`.

The key point being that the user has to open the PWA, in order for Chrome to check if the manifest has been updated.

Full details are at [How Chrome handles updates to the web app manifest](https://web.dev/manifest-updates/)